# how to do right join where key is null in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to do a right join where key is null in python pandas.
That is, can I join DateFrames to produce only values from the right that do not match the left?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas left join where right is null on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487263/pandas-left-join-where-right-is-null-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is best expressed as an index selection operation.   To find all indices in one frame and not in another, try using the `-` operator on the two Dataframe `index` objects, as if the index objects were built-in python set objects.  for example:

```
In [1]: dfa = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5)}, index=range(5))

In [2]: dfb = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10, 15)}, index=range(3,8))

In [3]: dfa
Out[3]: 
   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

In [4]: dfb
Out[4]: 
    A
3  10
4  11
5  12
6  13
7  14

In [5]: dfb.loc[set(dfb.index) - set(dfa.index)]
Out[5]: 
    A
5  12
6  13
7  14
```

Comment: Had to do:  `dfb.loc[set(dfb.index) - set(dfa.index)]`. Without adding the`set`s, it didn't work for me  in `pandas` `0.20.3` with `Index` `dtype='object'`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a dummy column of ones in each dataframe, use pd.merge() to right join the dataframes, and then use a mask to filter out the nulls.

```
In [1]: dfa = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(4, 8)})
In [2]: dfb = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(6, 10)})
In [3]: dfa['ones'] = 1
In [4]: dfb['ones'] = 1
In [5]: dfa 
Out[5]: 
   A  ones
0  4  1
1  5  1
2  6  1
3  7  1

In [6]: dfb 
Out[6]: 
   A  ones
0  6  1
1  7  1
2  8  1
3  9  1

In [7]: df = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, on = 'A', how = 'right')
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
    A   ones_x  ones_y
0   6   1       1
1   7   1       1
2   8   NaN     1
3   9   NaN     1

In [8]: df[df.ones_x.notnull()][['A']]
Out[8]: 
    A
0   6
1   7
```

Answer (score 1):

A more compact solution with merge:

```
df = dfa.merge(dfb, indicator='i', how='outer').query('i == "right_only"').drop('i', 1)
print (df)
```

Solution taken from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487564/9539462

Answer (score 0):

Use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html#pandas.Index.difference

```py
import pandas a pd


dfa = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5)}, index=range(5))
Out[13]:
   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4


dfb = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10, 15)}, index=range(3,8))
Out[14]:
    A
3  10
4  11
5  12
6  13
7  14

dfb[dfb.index.difference(dfa.index)]
Out[15]:
    A
5  12
6  13
7  14
```