# right join where key is null in python pandas with MultiIndexes

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have two dataframes with MultiIndexes, and I need to right join them and then get the items on the right side which *didn't* have a key match.

The preferred answer for [how to do right join where key is null in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915118/how-to-do-right-join-where-key-is-null-in-python-pandas) suggests to do something like this:

```
In [1]: dfa = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5)}, index=range(5))

In [2]: dfb = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10, 15)}, index=range(3,8))

In [3]: dfa
Out[3]: 
   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

In [4]: dfb
Out[4]: 
    A
3  10
4  11
5  12
6  13
7  14

In [5]: dfb.loc[dfb.index - dfa.index]
Out[5]: 
    A
5  12
6  13
7  14
```

but when I try that with my code, I get an error:

```
TypeError: cannot perform __sub__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex'>
```

What options do I have given that MultiIndexes can't be subtracted from one another?

Comment: Crazy idea, can you modify your example with something that [actually uses a MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a join to get the items that did not match. A simpler way would be using the below:

```
df = dfb[dfb.index.isin(dfa.index) == False]
```

Alternate way, that uses join, would be:

```
a = dfa.join(dfb, lsuffix='a', how='right')
a[a.Aa.isnull()][['A']]
```

I do not know your exact requirement, but to get the result, 1st is probably a neater way of achieving the goal. Regards