# pandas left join where right is null on multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two pandas df x and y, both with the same 3 columns A B C (not nullable). I need to create a new df z, obtained by "subtracting from x the rows which are entirely identical to the rows of y", i.e. a

```
x left join y on x.A=y.A and x.B=y.B and x.C=y.C
where y.A is null
```

How would I do that? Got stuck with indexes, concat, merge, join, ...

Example:

```
dataframe x
A    B    C
q1   q2   q3
q4   q2   q3
q7   q2   q9

dataframe y
A    B    C
q4   q2   q3

dataframe z
A    B    C
q1   q2   q3
q7   q2   q9
```

Comment: Can you create data sample and expected output?

Comment: Sure, example added

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with indicator and filter only rows from `left` `DataFrame`:

```
df = x.merge(y, indicator='i', how='outer').query('i == "left_only"').drop('i', axis=1)
print (df)
    A   B    C
0  q1  q2   q3
2  q7  q2  q93
```

In earlier versions of pandas, it may be necessary to replace `.drop('i', axis=1)` with `.drop('i',1)`.  The former is necessary to avoid warnings in later versions of Pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few other ways to remove certain lines from a dataframe using another dataframe:

```
pd.concat([dfx,dfy]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

or

```
dfx.loc[[i not in dfy.to_records(index = False) for i in dfx.to_records(index = False)]]
```

or

```
dfx.loc[~dfx.apply(tuple,axis=1).isin(dfy.to_records(index = False))]
```

or

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(dfx).symmetric_difference(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(dfy)).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)

pd.DataFrame(set(dfx.apply(tuple,axis=1)).symmetric_difference(dfy.apply(tuple,axis=1)))
```