# SQL to equivalent pandas - Merge on columns where column is null

Tags: mysql, pandas

I opened up this new question because I'm not sure the user's request and wording matched each other: [pandas left join where right is null on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487263/pandas-left-join-where-right-is-null-on-multiple-columns)

What is the equivalent pandas code to this SQL? Contextually we're finding entries from a column in table_y that aren't in table_x with respect to several columns.

```sql
SELECT
   table_x.column,
   table_x.column2,
   table_x.column3,
   table_y.column,
   table_y.column2,
   table_y.column3,
FROM table_x
LEFT JOIN table_y
   ON table_x.column = table_y.column
   ON table_x.column2 = table_y.column2
WHERE
   table_y.column2 is NULL
```

Is this it?

```py
columns_join = ['column', 'column2']
data_y = data_y.set_index(columns_join)
data_x = data_x.set_index(columns_join)

data_diff = pandas.concat([data_x, data_y]).drop_duplicates(keep=False) # any row not in both

# Select the diff representative from each dataset - in case datasets are too large
x1 = data_x[data_x.index.isin(data_diff.index)]
x2 = data_y[data_y.index.isin(data_diff.index)]

# Perform an outer join with the joined indices from each set,
# then remove the entries only contributed from table_x 
data_compare = x1.merge(x2, how = 'outer', indicator=True, left_index=True, right_index=True)

data_compare_final = (
    data_compare
    .query('_merge == left_join')
    .drop('_merge', axis=1)
)
```

I don't think that's equivalent because we only removed entries from table_x that aren't in the join based on multiple columns. I think we have to continue and compare the column against table_y.

```
data_compare = data_compare.reset_index().set_index('column2')
data_y = data_y.reset_index().set_index('column2')
mask_column2 = data_y.index.isin(data_compare.index)
result = data_y[~mask_column2]
```

Comment: Kindly provide sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: There are some weird edge cases with this. I'll be able to answer my own question later this afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an equivalent that amounts to setting the index to the join column(s), union'ing the tables, dropping the duplicates, and performing a cross join between the contributions to the union. From there, one can select

left_only for this equivalent SQL

```sql
SELECT
   table_x.*,
   table_y.*
FROM table_x
LEFT JOIN table_y
   ON table_x.column = table_y.column
   ON table_x.column2 = table_y.column2
WHERE
   table_y.column2 is NULL
```

right_only for this equivalent SQL

```sql
SELECT
   table_x.*,
   table_y.*
FROM table_y
LEFT JOIN table_x
   ON table_y.column = table_x.column
   ON table_y.column2 = table_x.column2
WHERE
   table_x.column2 is NULL
```

```py
def create_dataframe_joined_diffs(dataframe_prod, dataframe_new, columns_join):
    """
    Set the indices to the columns_key
    Concat the dataframes and remove duplicates
    Select the diff representative from each dataset
    Reset the indices and perform an outer join

    Pseudo-SQL:

    SELECT
        UNIQUE(*)
    FROM dataframe_prod
    OUTER JOIN dataframe_new
        ON columns_join
    """
    data_new = dataframe_new.set_index(columns_join)
    data_prod = dataframe_prod.set_index(columns_join)

    # Get any row not in both (may be removing too many)
    data_diff = pandas.concat([data_prod, data_new]).drop_duplicates(keep=False) # any row not in both
    # Select the diff representative from each dataset
    x1 = data_prod[data_prod.index.isin(data_diff.index)]
    x2 = data_new[data_new.index.isin(data_diff.index)]

    # Perform an outer join and keep the joined indices from each set
    # Sort the columns to make them easier to compare
    data_compare = x1.merge(x2, how = 'outer', indicator=True, left_index=True, right_index=True).sort_index(axis=1)

    return data_compare
```

```py
mask_left = dataframe_compare['_merge'] == 'left_only'
mask_right = dataframe_compare['_merge'] == 'right_only'
```

Comment: If someone comes up with a simpler way, I'll happily accept their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without test data it is a bit difficult to be sure that this helps but you can try:

```py
# Only if columns to join on in the right dataframe have the same name as columns in left
table_y[['col_join_1', 'col_join_2']] = table_y[['column', 'column2']] # Else this is not needed

# Merge left (LEFT JOIN)
table_merged = table_x.merge(
    table_y,
    how='left',
    left_on=['column', 'column2'],
    right_on=['col_join_1', 'col_join_2'],
    suffixes=['_x', '_y']
)

# Filter dataframe
table_merged = table_merged.loc[
    table_merged.column2_y.isna(),
    ['column_x', 'column2_x', 'column3_x', 'column_y', 'column2_y', 'column3_y']
]
```